# (x <= y <=z) condition syntax in ISO C?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I've seen the condition syntax as follows, shown a lot in example code to check if an integral value `y` is between two bounds `x` and `z`:

```
if (x <= y <= z) { //... }
```

I thought I'd used this before myself, but in a small piece of code Im running a test on, the condition always evaluates to true...
Doubting my own memory here now because I'm near sure I've used it before! Is the syntax allowable in ISO C? Am I just expecting it to do something it's not meant to do?

The old fashioned:

```
if (x >= y && x <= z) { //... }
```

still works a charm so I haven't quite made it to the doddering stage of recall just yet ;)

Comment: If you managed to compile and run that then it's in all likelihood "allowable" - but it most likely does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen It compiles with a warning with gcc: *"comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning"*

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: How nice of GCC to catch that for you.

Comment: It's logically wrong. However, if you study the syntax and meaning of C operators, you'll realiza by yourself that it's not a correct code.

Comment: @pablo1977: Correct in what sense? It's valid C syntax, it compiles, it runs. It doesn't semantically do what many people would expect it to do though.

Comment: I did get a warning "Comparison between pointer and integer" but my fuzzled grey matter didn't understand correctly that it applied to the comparison rather than the comparison value (a pointer)!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: "Correct" in the sense of the question, which pretends that `x <= y <= z` will have the usual mathematical meaning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>I guess that all `x`, `y`, `z`  are some integral type like `int` or `long`. For [floating point](https://floating-point-gui.de/) notice that `NaN != NaN`.....</sup>

The first `if (x <= y <= z)` is wrong. It is parsed as `if ((x<=y) <= z)`. A compare returns a boolean value, which, when used in some integral context, is promoted to 0 (for false) or 1 (for true). So when `x <= y` the test behave as `if (1 <= z)` and when on the contrary `x > y` the test is equivalent to `if (0 <= z)`

When asked to give all warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall`) a good compiler (such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) would warn you.

> Is the syntax allowable in ISO C?

Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and this [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the documentation of your C compiler. Study, for inspiration, the source code of *existing* [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.org/)). You are unlikely to see code such as  `if (x <= y <= z)`. That syntax is allowable, but weird.

<sup>BTW, in the unlikely case -I never meet that, but I do code in C since 1980s- you really mean `if ((x<=y) <= z)` I feel that the code is bizarre enough to need an explicit comment, or code `if (((x<=y)?1:0) <= z)`</sup>

Comment: You assume correct, edited OP to clarify. The end of your first sup line made me thing of Adam West...